# Concat bytes and string in python

Tags: python, string, macos, byte, concatenation

Firstly, I produced Mac code:

mac = hmac.new(b'key', b'yeliz', hashlib.sha256).digest()

Secondly, I wanted to concat 'yeliz' with its Mac.

mac+'yeliz'

But I got below error: 
        TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Is there a way to concat two different types? Or without encoding string? Because I need to see plaintext with its Mac.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I achieved to solve the problem as below in a for loop:

```
  digest_maker = hmac.new(b'key',b'',digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
  digest_maker.update(message)
  digest = digest_maker.hexdigest()
  newstring=str(newstring)+"+"+ str(digest)
```